# I hung my head in shame

Tags: meaning

Does the phrase "I hung my head in shame" mean that the person hanged himself? Suicide?

Comment: [hang head (in shame)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hang+head)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, it doesn't mean this. It is an idiom:

> **Hang one's head:** let it fall forward (e.g., when ashamed); a downward droop or bend

- After the teacher caught me cheating, I hung my head in shame.
- Athletes caught taking drugs should hang their heads in shame.

When a person commits suicide or is executed by hanging, we use *hang/hanged*. "Hung" is never used in such cases. e.g.,

- He was *hanged* for murder. (executed)
- He said he would *hang* himself. (suicide)

Answer (score 1):

This paints a picture of a person with their chin on their chest, or at least on their collar bone. It is a posture of depression and humility.

It might be literal, or figurative.